# Conditional output using jq

Tags: json, jq, exit-code

I have JSON input like the following.

- `{"value":{"error":"no such element","message":"no such element: xxx"}`
- `{"value":null}`

I want to use `jq` to return with an exit status of 0 (print nothing) for the second case, and print `no such element: xxx` to stderr and return an exit status of 1 for the first case.

How can I achieve this in `jq`?

Answer (score 5):

One way to specify the exit code is with the built-in filter `halt_error`.  To meet your specifications as I understand them, you could thus write:

```
 .value
 | if . then .error | halt_error(1)
   else null | halt_error(0)
   end
```

See the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) for details and to explore variations (e.g. to add "\n").

Comment: That requires using `-r` and `>&2` to meet the spec. Using `.error+"\n"|halt_error(1)` instead of `(.error, (null|halt_error(1)))` simplifies the code and removes the need for both `-r` and `>&2`.

Comment: @ikegami - Yes, I missed one of the requirements and updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand this question (and also what I was looking for before coming across this) is that you want the `jq` program to exit with different status codes depending on which type of input is read **first**.

##### file.json

```json
{"value":{"error":"no such element","message":"no such element: xxx"}}
{"value":null}
```

Using the builtin [`halt`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#halt) and [`halt_error`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#halt_error,halt_error(exit_code)), you can accomplish this:

```
jq -n 'inputs | .value | if .error then "\(.message)\n" | halt_error(1) else halt end' < file.json
```

The only difference between this and the current [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67945113/2089675) is that `jq` will actually quit after it reads the first input, and will ignore the rest of the file.